# add to the database with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm really blocked! 3 days with this method "create" !!!!!
0 errors, 0 warning and the method does not work!
i'm really about to lose my mind 
can any one here check with me !

is the problem with the enumaration or something ?

this is my model :

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
namespace mvc_depences.Models
{
    public class Projet
    {
        public enum Etat
        {
            En_Cours, Termine, Annule
        }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ProjetId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "nomP")]
        public string nomP { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "DateDebut")]
        public DateTime DateDebut { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "DateFinPrevue")]
        public DateTime DateFinPrevue { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "DateFinReele")]
        public DateTime DateFinReele { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public String Description { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "etat")]
        public Etat? etat { get; set; }
        [Column("UtilisateurID")]
        public int UtilisateurID { get; set; }
        public virtual Utilisateur U { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Depence> D { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Encaissement> E { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my controller :

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using mvc_depences.Models;
namespace mvc_depences.Controllers
{
    public class ProjetController : Controller
    {
        private BD_GestionDepences db = new BD_GestionDepences();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProjetId,nomP,DateDebut,DateFinPrevue,DateFinReele,etat,Description,UtilisateurID")]Projet projet)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Projets.Add(projet);
                db.SaveChanges();
            };
            return View(projet);
        }
        public ActionResult Projet_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            IQueryable<Projet> projets = db.Projets;
            DataSourceResult result = projets.ToDataSourceResult(request, projet => new
            {
                ProjetId = projet.ProjetId,
                nomP = projet.nomP,
                DateDebut = projet.DateDebut,
                DateFinPrevue = projet.DateFinPrevue,
                DateFinReele = projet.DateFinReele,
                etat = projet.etat,
            });
            return Json(result);
        }
        //public ActionResult Index()
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}
    }
}
```

and my view "create"

```js
@model mvc_depences.Models.Projet
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/admin.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Projet", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <br />
        <legend class="legend">Ajouter Un Nouveau Projet</legend>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <br />
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label class="cke_label" for="NomP">Nom</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom Projet" data-val="true" required="" data-val-length="Taille max  est 50 caracteres !! " data-val-length-max="50" id="nom" name="nom">
                                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="nom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br /><br />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="cke_label" for="UtilisateurID">UtilisateurID</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UtilisateurID" data-val="true" required="" data-val-length="Taille max  est 50 caracteres !! " data-val-length-max="50" id="UtilisateurID" name="UtilisateurID">
                                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="UtilisateurID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br/><br/>
                            <!--Date Debut !!-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="cke_label" for="DateDebut">Date Debut</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header text" style="width: 245px;">
                                        <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                                            <input data-val="true" class="text k-input" style="width: 100%;" data-val-date="The field DateDebut must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ DateDebut est requis." id="DateDebut" name="DateDebut" type="text" data-role="datepicker" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="DateDebut_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
                                            <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="DateDebut_dateview">
                                                <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <script>
                                        jQuery(function () {
                                            jQuery("#DateDebut").kendoDatePicker({ "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "min": new Date(1950, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "max": new Date(2000, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <span class="text" data-valmsg-for="DateDebut" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br /><br />
                            <!--Date fin Prevue !!-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="cke_label" for="DateFinPrevue">Date Fin Prevue</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header text" style="width: 245px;">
                                        <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                                            <input data-val="true" class="text k-input" style="width: 100%;" data-val-date="The field DateFinPrevue must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ DateFinPrevue est requis." id="DateFinPrevue" name="DateFinPrevue" type="text" data-role="datepicker" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="DateFinPrevue_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
                                            <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="DateFinPrevue_dateview">
                                                <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <script>
                                        jQuery(function () {
                                            jQuery("#DateFinPrevue").kendoDatePicker({ "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "min": new Date(1950, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "max": new Date(2000, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <span class="text" data-valmsg-for="DateFinPrevue" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br /><br />
                            <!--Date fin Reele !!-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="cke_label" for="DateFinReele">Date Fin Reele</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header text" style="width: 245px;">
                                        <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                                            <input data-val="true" class="text k-input" style="width: 100%;" data-val-date="The field DateFinReele must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ DateFinReele est requis." id="DateFinReele" name="DateFinReele" type="text" data-role="datepicker" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="DateFinReele_dateview" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
                                            <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" role="button" aria-controls="DateFinReele_dateview">
                                                <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-calendar">select</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <script>
                                        jQuery(function () {
                                            jQuery("#DateFinReele").kendoDatePicker({ "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "min": new Date(1950, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), "max": new Date(2000, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <span class="text" data-valmsg-for="DateFinReele" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br /><br />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="cke_label" for="Description">Description</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <textarea rows="6" cols="40"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br /><br />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="cke_label" for="etat">Etat</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div align="justify">
                                        <br>
                                        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="En_Cours" checked> En Cours<br>
                                        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Termine"> Terminé<br>
                                        <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Annule"> Annulé<br>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-left:400px;margin-top:120px">
                                <div class="col-md-12" style="width:350px">
                                    <input id="Submit" class="btn btn-default" name="actionType" type="submit" value="Engeristrer" style="width:150px" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Put a break point on your receiving controller method and step through the code. My first guess is that your `ModelState` is not valid, which would make sense as to why there are no errors (since invalid model state means it would skip trying to save to the DB)

Comment: where should i put the breakpoint ? i geuss it doesn't miss any

Comment: Put a breakpoint on 'if(ModelState.IsValid)', inside the method 'Create', then tell us what happens next.

Comment: i already added it

Comment: hi again ! so .. my problem isn't solved